# Minimum Connection Pool Size

Tags: asp.net, connection

I have a website with high traffic.

Maybe I will increase minimum connections pool, to 100.

This is too high? Website have 10000 pageviews/day

Thanks

Comment: You may want to be a little more specify. Why are you increasing the connection pool size, is there a related issue, what do you hope to accomplish? What type of server is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems awfully high. 10,000 pageviews per day means you get less than 1 pageview per 10 seconds on average.

It would depend on your database server, but I doubt it can effectively perform 100 queries at the same time. Even if it can, it's not likely to ever occur, so setting the *minimum* pool size to 100 makes no sense.

If you're running out of connections in your pool, you should check if you're disposing your connections properly.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the connection pool is only helpful if your server can handle all the open connections. If you are trying to accomplish faster response times you should look into caching data where you can and reducing total server request/responses